# TinyMCE strips line breaks on mceAddControl

Tags: tinymce, wysiwyg, wp-editor

I'm using `wp_editor` to add wysiwyg fields to admin edit screens. Each wysiwyg lives within a draggable meta box. Since TinyMCE has issues with dragging, I'm using the following code:

```
// on the dragstart event
tinyMCE.execCommand('mceRemoveControl', false, the_editor_id);

// on the dragstop event
tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddControl', false, the_editor_id);
```

The problem is that, when `mceAddControl` is fired, all newlines and linebreaks are stripped from the text. Has anyone been able to solve this issue?

**Before dragstart:**

[image: before dragstart]

**After dragstop:**

[image: after dragstop]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that TinyMCE has it's own `autop` setting, so if you kill it before the sort and then put it back you should be good to go!

Check out the `autop` setting handling in this snippet:

```
<script>
(function($) {

    // by default, wpautop will be true
    var wpautop = true;

    // this function wraps subsequent additions of TinyMCE
    $(function() {

        // save the original state of TinyMCE's wpautop
        wpautop = tinyMCE.settings.wpautop;

        // bind to our custom event that fires when a new TinyMCE is added
        $(document).on( 'attachments/new', function( event ) {

            // initialize the applicable TinyMCE instances
            $('.attachments-field-wysiwyg:not(.ready)').init_wysiwyg();

        });

        // initialize the applicable TinyMCE instances
        $('.attachments-field-wysiwyg').init_wysiwyg();
    });

    // init TinyMCE
    $.fn.init_wysiwyg = function() {
        this.each(function() {

            // a flag for this instance
            $(this).addClass('ready');

            var input_id = $(this).attr('id');

            // create wysiwyg
            tinyMCE.settings.theme_advanced_buttons2 += ',code';        // add HTML button
            tinyMCE.settings.wpautop = false;                           // force wpautop to false to preserve linebreaks
            tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddControl', false, input_id);      // add TinyMCE control
            tinyMCE.settings.wpautop = wpautop;                         // reset the original wpautop setting
        });
    };

    // bind to our custom event that fires when sorting starts
    $(document).on('attachments/sortable_start', function(event, ui) {

        // force wpautop to be false (and by doing so preserve our line breaks)
        tinyMCE.settings.wpautop = false;

        $('.attachments-field-wysiwyg').each(function() {
            tinyMCE.execCommand('mceRemoveControl', false, $(this).attr('id'));
        });

    });

    // bind to our custom event that fires when when sorting starts
    $(document).on('attachments/sortable_stop', function(event, ui) {

        $('.attachments-field-wysiwyg').each(function() {
            tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddControl', false, $(this).attr('id'));
        });

        // reset the original wpautop setting
        tinyMCE.settings.wpautop = wpautop;
    });

})(jQuery);
</script>
```

Snippet pulled from my WordPress plugin, Attachments: https://github.com/jchristopher/attachments/blob/3.3.2/classes/fields/class.field.wysiwyg.php

Comment: Can you elaborate? Maybe some sample code? Link only answers are discouraged. If that link goes bad this answer becomes useless.

Comment: Absolutely! That makes perfect sense, sorry, new to StackExchange! Added a code sample from the link.

Comment: Originally, you had a link to the source. Please add that back in addition to the code posted so that the code posted is properly attributed.

Comment: Sure thing, just added it back in.

Comment: This is cool ! but this solution made WP to save the content as html rather than the raw text, do you know the workaround to this? Thanks!